# WCF Service with different amount of methods ( Endpoints)

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf

I'm working on a project that uses WCF,but I'm unable to solve a problem.

I have two solutions ***Project A*** and ***Project B***. The actual error is the following : when it tries to create an instance of the ***OAuthServiceClient*** inside of project B, it generates the following error

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'SSOWebService.IOAuthService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

This happens, I believe, because of the difference in methods of the WCF Service of ***Project B(30 endpoints)*** and ***Project B(15 endpoints)***

I can add the code here if that is of use.

Comment: According to the errors, it seems that there is no endpoint configuration in the client configuration file. how about you think of?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I ended up fixing the problem already, All I had to do was remove the old reference file, and add it again. That fixed it
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72K90.png)